# Spy Kit + Oddly Uneven: How can I determine what should occur?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-joke-cards

Suppose a creature is equipped with [Spy Kit](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=416836), and [Oddly Uneven](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=439404) gets cast. Then in order to figure out whether the creature is destroyed, I need to determine whether the total number of words in all names of non legendary creatures is even or odd.

What is the best way (i.e., simplest database query) to accomplish this?

(This originally came up [on Mark Rosewater's tumblr](http://markrosewater.tumblr.com/post/170278478263/say-i-put-a-spy-kit-into-an-un-deck-i-play-it).)

Comment: In the interest of speed of resolution, I'd recommend flipping a coin, and using that result for the rest of the match...

Answer (score 12):

Having "all the names" does not mean the creature has one mega-name; it means it has multiple distinct names.

Does it have a name with an odd number of words in it? Yes.

Does it have a name with even number of words in it? Yes.

Therefore, it will be destroyed no matter which mode is chosen.

Comment: A split card is another example of a card with multiple names. Except when a spell, [this card](https://magiccards.info/dgm/en/121a.html) has names "Alive" and "Well". It also has two sets of types. (It used to have two mana costs and CMCs too, but that changed.)

Comment: While this answer clears up an incorrect assumption that the asker has made; it doesn't actually answer the question being asked. It just avoids the need for the question to be asked.

Comment: Should that be "does *not* mean the creature has one mega-name"?

Comment: @jwodder: Apparently so, since that's what the original version said. It was lost in a later copyedit.

Comment: My apologies. .

Comment: @GendoIkari, Not quite. Don't get distracted by the wording of the question; it's frequently wrong. The OP does not "need to determine whether the total number of words in all names of non legendary creatures is even or odd." The actual question is how to handle Spy Kit with Oddly Uneven --this is even explicitly stated in the title-- and that question was answered.

Comment: @ikegami I see that I missed the question title; indeed that makes it clear what the user really wanted. (Without that title, it could have been a valid interpretation that the user wanted to know how to count words in all card names; and was using that interaction as an incorrect example of why he wanted it).

Comment: @Gendolkari, There's no reason to count words in all card names. You gotta find out what the person really wants to know, and it's how Spy Kit works (with or without Oddly Uneven).